# get data from nodejs to frontend js for google maps but stuck in retrieving it looking for ways to solve it

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

My NodeJS `GET` route:

```
router.get('/stores', function (req, res, next) {
errorMsg = req.flash('error')[0];
successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];

Product.find(function (err, products) {
    // console.log(products)
    res.render('admin/stores', {
        layout: 'admin-map.hbs',
        stores: products,
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
        GOOGLE_APIKEY: process.env.GOOGLE_APIKEY,
        noErrors: 1
    });
});
```

The route `/stores` returns json data which holds **latitude** and **longitude** and I want it in my script tag of map.html with loop, to render the pins on the map. Below, the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
   <script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

   <script>
     function loadMap() {
        alert(this.stores);
        var mapOptions = {
           center:new google.maps.LatLng(17.433053, 78.412172),
           zoom:5
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"),mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(17.433053, 78.412172),
           map: map,
           draggable:true,
           icon:'/scripts/img/logo-footer.png'
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
     }
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
    </head>
</html>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. How do you pass `stores` from template to script? and how is `loadMap()` called? Does `this.stores` contain the data you want in this example? (if it's undefined, try `window.stores` instead.). Or is it perhaps looping through the stores that is your problem?

Comment: trying to pass data from ( /stores) to the longitude and latitude in the script                                             load map is being called onload pf windows in hbs we do it like {{#each stores}} to retrieve store data but same is not the case in the script tag so trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is inside fronted script i can have an object declared globally and this double flower brackets works fine with them

```
 <script>
     function loadMap() {
        alert(this.stores);
        var mapOptions = {
           center:new google.maps.LatLng(17.433053, 78.412172),
           zoom:5
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"),mapOptions);
      {{#each stores}}
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(17.433053, 78.412172),
           map: map,
           draggable:true,
           icon:'/scripts/img/logo-footer.png'
        });
{{/each}}

        marker.setMap(map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });

        infowindow.open(map,marker);
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to follow two steps

**1. Pass data from hbs to script**

Using triple brackets syntax

```
<script>
  let stores = {{{ stores }}}; // the triple brackets
  console.log('Data : ', stores);

  function loadMap() {
    ...
```

Check if data is being printed in console? If yes your data is available in the front-end script and you can

**2. Loop through it**

```
    ...
    for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
      // the JS loop instead of hbs one, because we are on front-end

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(stores[i].lat, stores[i].lng), // whatever applies
         map: map,
         draggable:true,
         icon:'/scripts/img/logo-footer.png'
      });
    }
```

And donot need to call `setMap()`, you have already set the map in `map:  map` above